# Duplicate Project in Things 3 Using Applescript

Tags: applescript

I have tried the following:

```
tell application "Things3"
    set newToDo to duplicate project "project1" to list "Today" with properties {name:"project2"}
end tell
```

and I get

```
Things3 got an error: Projects can not be copied. (-1717)
```

Now I have manually created `project2` and I'm trying

```
tell application "Things3"
    repeat with aToDo in to dos of project "project1"
        duplicate aToDo to project "project2"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Which gives me

```
Things3 got an error: Can’t set project "project2" to item 1 of every to do of project "project1".
```

I'm inferring that I have the Applescript syntax wrong for this second one.

However, while experimenting, I saw an error about not being able to move objects to a project container but I've forgotten what code it was. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that you can move to dos, except to a list. There is a Things3 applescript guide which explains how to move to a list but says nothing about projects or anything else. Kind of strange that it does not contain the word 'duplicate' but the user interface does have duplicate project.

Comment: Agreed that it is odd. I ultimately just ended up using an Applescript to trigger the user interface key commands, which is slower and requires me to be careful not to interact with anything while it is duplicating but it gets the job done.

Comment: It is a little more work but I will actually be rewriting this task using the [Things URL Scheme](https://culturedcode.com/things/support/articles/2803573/) `json` option, which is much more intuitive and flexible. I'll just recreate the template with a new name when needed.